# A column in my dataframe has dictionary values, some of which have no ending bracket, detect these values

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I am trying to detect dictionary values that are properly formatted vs those that aren't (missing a curly bracket at the end, for example) in a column in my dataframe.

```
{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "3333"
```

using

```
df = df.where(~df.column.contains('}'))
```

Does not return the full row value... I will get:

{'Id': '1'

What I want to get:

```
{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "3333"
```

How do I get the above answer in PySpark?

Note, I want to then get the ending value of ea. dictionary value missing an ending bracket. So example...

```
"3333"
```

Eventually.

Note: Yes, the double-quotes are not a mistake... actually recorded. Just bad data.

Comment: what is the data type of that column?

Comment: The data type is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `endswith` column method.

here's an example

```py
spark.createDataFrame([('''{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "3333"''',), ('''{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "1234"}''',)], ['col1']). \
    filter(func.col('col1').endswith('}') == False). \
    withColumn('blah', func.trim(func.reverse(func.split('col1', ':')).getItem(0))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------------------+------+
# |col1                                    |blah  |
# +----------------------------------------+------+
# |{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "3333"|"3333"|
# +----------------------------------------+------+
```

---

input was

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|col1                                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
|{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "3333" |
|{'Id': '1', 'state': 'FL', "zip": "1234"}|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I do not get the right answer still unfortunately. Mind these are CSVs I am getting data from.

hm = df.filter(F.col('col').endswith('}') == False). \
    withColumn('blah', F.trim(F.reverse(F.split('col', ':')).getItem(0)))

hm.select('blah').show(1, truncate=False) 

Gives me:  '1'

Comment: I've shown you the input and output in my answer. Is your input different from that? @purple_plop

Comment: @purple_plop check how the data looks like after you read the csv file. I think it is being read incorrectly and gets split by commas by default

Comment: You are right, it's how the csv is being read. The dictionary values with missing ending curly brackets are only being read to the first key even when there's several.

Comment: new note: the field is a JSON field as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing them into JSON (assuming all entries are serializable here):

```py
def can_be_parsed(dict_str):
    try:
        json.loads(dict_str)
    except (json.JSONDecodeError, ValueError):
        return False
    return True 
df.iloc[:, df.columns.map(can_be_parsed)]
```